# X11 Mouse Acceleration setting

Tags: macos, mouse, x11, xquartz

X11 that I am using (XQuartz 2.7.5 (xorg-server 1.14.4)) with Yosemite has very high acceleration with the mouse (external or trackpad). Is there a way to lower the acceleration or remove it all together?

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently using [SmoothMouse](http://smoothmouse.com/). İt disables Mac OS X mouse acceleration

[image: screenshot]

Comment: what does this do and how do you make it work? A link on its own is not a good answer

Comment: Currently the website is not functional so I have no clue what this program does.